# How to consume External SOAP based web services in java?

Tags: java, xml, webservice-client

I need to consume http://indblrp2p03.ad.infosys.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/sdef_/INFYPE/SOAP_WS_SC_SEARCH/wsdl11/ws_policy/rpc?sap-client=200 SOAP based webservice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style"   xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsoap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:n1="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
 <wsdl:documentation>
 <sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl="http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl" /> 
 </wsdl:documentation>
 <wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required="true" /> 
 <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="IF_IF__-infype_-SOAP_WS_SC_SEARCH">
 <sapsession:Session xmlns:sapsession="http://www.sap.com/webas/630/soap/features/session/">
<sapsession:enableSession>false</sapsession:enableSession> 
</sapsession:Session>
</wsp:Policy>
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="OP_IF_OP__-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWs">
<sapcomhnd:enableCommit xmlns:sapcomhnd="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/commit/">false</sapcomhnd:enableCommit> 
<sapblock:enableBlocking xmlns:sapblock="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/blocking/">true</sapblock:enableBlocking> 
  <saptrhnw05:required xmlns:saptrhnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/transaction/">no</saptrhnw05:required> 
  <saprmnw05:enableWSRM xmlns:saprmnw05="http://www.sap.com/NW05/soap/features/wsrm/">false</saprmnw05:enableWSRM> 
</wsp:Policy>
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<xsd:simpleType name="byte16">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:base64Binary">
 <xsd:maxLength value="16" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char1">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="1" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char10">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="10" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="char12">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="12" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char14">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="14" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char2">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="2" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char20">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="20" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char21">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="21" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char220">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="220" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char30">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="30" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char32">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="32" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char40">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="40" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char50">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="50" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char54">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="54" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
   <xsd:simpleType name="char60">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="60" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char8">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="8" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="char80">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="80" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="cuky5">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="5" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="curr13.2">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
 <xsd:totalDigits value="13" /> 
 <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="curr15.2">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
 <xsd:totalDigits value="15" /> 
 <xsd:fractionDigits value="2" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="date">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:date">
  <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="numeric10">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="10" /> 
  <xsd:pattern value="\d*" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="numeric2">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="2" /> 
  <xsd:pattern value="\d*" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="numeric3">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="3" /> 
  <xsd:pattern value="\d*" /> 
   </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="numeric6">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
  <xsd:maxLength value="6" />
  <xsd:pattern value="\d*" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="quantum13.3">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
 <xsd:totalDigits value="13" /> 
 <xsd:fractionDigits value="3" /> 
  </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
 <xsd:simpleType name="unit3">
 <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
 <xsd:maxLength value="3" /> 
 </xsd:restriction>
 </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:complexType name="I">
 <xsd:sequence /> 
 </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:schema>
 <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style" xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
 <xsd:import namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" /> 
 <xsd:complexType name="Bapiret2">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="Type" type="n0:char1" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Id" type="n0:char20" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Number" type="n0:numeric3" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Message" type="n0:char220" /> 
 <xsd:element name="LogNo" type="n0:char20" /> 
 <xsd:element name="LogMsgNo" type="n0:numeric6" /> 
 <xsd:element name="MessageV1" type="n0:char50" /> 
 <xsd:element name="MessageV2" type="n0:char50" /> 
 <xsd:element name="MessageV3" type="n0:char50" /> 
 <xsd:element name="MessageV4" type="n0:char50" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Parameter" type="n0:char32" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Row" type="xsd:int" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Field" type="n0:char30" /> 
 <xsd:element name="System" type="n0:char10" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="_-infype_-strScLst">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="ScGuid" type="n0:byte16" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ScNo" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ScName" type="n0:char40" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ItemGuid" type="n0:byte16" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ItemNo" type="n0:numeric10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ItemName" type="n0:char40" /> 
 <xsd:element name="NetPrice" type="n0:curr13.2" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ItemTotal" type="n0:curr15.2" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Currency" type="n0:cuky5" /> 
 <xsd:element name="TotalValue" type="n0:curr15.2" /> 
 <xsd:element name="PoNo" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ConfNo" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ScStatus" type="n0:numeric2" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ScStatusDesc" type="n0:char60" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ProductCat" type="n0:char20" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ProductCatDesc" type="n0:char80" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Quantity" type="n0:quantum13.3" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Uom" type="n0:unit3" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ProductType" type="n0:char2" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Purchteam" type="n0:char8" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ProductId" type="n0:char54" /> 
 <xsd:element name="CatalogId" type="n0:char20" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Catalogitem" type="n0:char40" /> 
 <xsd:element name="SupplierId" type="n0:char32" /> 
 <xsd:element name="SupplierName" type="n0:char40" /> 
 <xsd:element name="Flag" type="n0:char1" /> 
 <xsd:element name="ScNoCumItemno" type="n0:char21" /> 
 <xsd:element name="CreatedAt" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="CreatedBy" type="n0:char12" /> 
  <xsd:element name="ChangedAt" type="n0:char10" /> 
  <xsd:element name="ChangedBy" type="n0:char12" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="_-infype_-strRelatedDoc">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="SourceDoc" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="RelatedDoc" type="n0:char10" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="_-infype_-strDocumentSrch">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="DocNo" type="n0:char10" /> 
 <xsd:element name="DocName" type="n0:char40" /> 
 <xsd:element name="DocDateFrom" type="n0:date" /> 
 <xsd:element name="DocDateTo" type="n0:date" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="_-infype_-strStatus">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="Status" type="xsd:int" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="TableOfBapiret2">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:Bapiret2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
 </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="TableOf_-infype_-strScLst">
 <xsd:sequence>
 <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:_-infype_-strScLst" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="TableOf_-infype_-strRelatedDoc">
  <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:_-infype_-strRelatedDoc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="TableOf_-infype_-strStatus">
   <xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="item" type="tns:_-infype_-strStatus" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
  </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="_-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWs">
  <wsdl:part name="EtReturn" type="tns:TableOfBapiret2" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="EtScList" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strScLst" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="EtScPo" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strRelatedDoc" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IsScSearch" type="tns:_-infype_-strDocumentSrch" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="ItScStatus" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strStatus" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvApprover" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvBuyer" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvCategoryId" type="n1:char20" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvCompletedCarts" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvDashboard" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvDbSearch" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvItemDesc" type="n1:char40" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvNoOfRecords" type="xsd:int" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvPoNumber" type="n1:char10" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvPurcGrp" type="n1:char14" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvPurcOrg" type="n1:char14" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvRequester" type="n1:char10" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvSupplier" type="n1:char10" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvTeamCart" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvTeamMember" type="n1:char12" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvUser" type="n1:char12" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvWithConf" type="n1:char1" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="IvWithPo" type="n1:char1" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="_-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWsResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="EtReturn" type="tns:TableOfBapiret2" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="EtScList" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strScLst" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="EtScPo" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strRelatedDoc" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="EvCount" type="n1:I" /> 
  <wsdl:part name="ItScStatus" type="tns:TableOf_-infype_-strStatus" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="_-infype_-SOAP_WS_SC_SEARCH">
  <wsp:Policy>
  <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#IF_IF__-infype_-SOAP_WS_SC_SEARCH" /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:operation name="_-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWs">
  <wsp:Policy>
   <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#OP_IF_OP__-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWs" /> 
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:input message="tns:_-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWs" /> 
  <wsdl:output message="tns:_-infype_-rfcShopcartSoapWsResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

For the same I have created a webservice client in Eclipse, in result of which following number of classes appeared some of whose structure is given as follows:

- _Infype_StrDocumentSrch,
- _Infype_StrRelatedDoc,
- _Infype_StrScLst,
- _Infype_StrStatus,
- Bapiret2 and I.java

I am able to make the connection with the URL but not able to get the parameters listed in the XML like itemNo, itemName etc from the backend. Can anyone pls tell me how to interact with these above classes and get the required paramters and its respective values.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse web service client tool must have generated some jsp pages. Check the TestClient.jsp and enter the values and see the responses that you get.

Comment: Its not displaying such jsp pages for me. It has generated only Infype_StrDocumentSrch,
•_Infype_StrRelatedDoc,
•_Infype_StrScLst, 
•_Infype_StrStatus,
•Bapiret2 and I.java files for me.

Comment: Can you please tell me other alternative for the same

Comment: I guess you should refer a basic tutorials like these http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/BottomUpWebService/BottomUpWebService.html and then It would be much better if you can explain your problem a bit to help you out

Comment: try to give some source code as well so that we all can sort out the issue

Comment: I have shared the webservice xml file......I need to set the values of certain parameters from the XML like IVUSER,IvPONumber etc in order to get the values of parameters of class •_Infype_StrRelatedDoc, •_Infype_StrScLst, •_Infype_StrStatus

Comment: On creating the webservice client I am not getting the jsp page to enter the input value in order to see the output.....do i need to write some additional code in main class....as i havent written any code in main class.....

Comment: Have you gone throught the tutorial that i referred you to..?

Comment: yeah have gone through that n followed the same, n i think there is problem in the xml file/webservice provided.......thats why not getting the required output.......